# Mongoid Query Document with Inclusion of Referenced Document ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have a group model. I want to query a group to see if user exists in it. Typically this is much easier using embedded documents but unfortunately I cannot do that in this case. In an embedded scenario I would do the following. How can I do this query in a referenced scenario.

**Note:**** I do not want to use *habtm* relationships.

**Query**

```
Matter.where(:'matter_counsels._id' => the_id)
```

**Classes**

```
class Matter
  include Mongoid::Document

  # Relationships
  has_many :matter_counsels # subclass of MatterRelationship
  has_many :matter_clients # subclass of MatterRelationship
  has_many :matter_opposing_parties # subclass of MatterRelationship
  has_many :matter_related_parties # subclass of MatterRelationship

end


class MatterRelationship
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :matter
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to admit the example I had above wasn't clear. I updated the problem along with my solution.

```
class Matter
  include Mongoid::Document

  # Relationships
  has_many :matter_counsels # subclass of MatterRelationship
  has_many :matter_clients # subclass of MatterRelationship
  has_many :matter_opposing_parties # subclass of MatterRelationship
  has_many :matter_related_parties # subclass of MatterRelationship

  # Finder Scopes
  class << self

    # finds a type of matter relationship by user
    def for_user(user,type)
      user_id = user.id.to_s
      matter_ids = MatterRelationship.where(contact_id: user_id, _type: type).collect{ |i| i.matter_id.to_s }
      where(:_id.in => matter_ids)
    end

  end

end
```